# How do I extract a TAR to a different destination directory

Tags: tar

On server A, I created a tar file (backup.tar.gz) of the entire website /www. The tar file includes the top-level directory www

On server B, I want to put those files into /public_html but not include the top level directory www

Of course, tar -xzif backup.tar.gz places everything into /public_html/www

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you make a tar.gz file of the content in the WWW folder, without WWW included. So you "cd /../../www" and make the files recursevly being added to the archive.

Comment: When I made the tar inside of /www I kept getting errors, as it keeps trying to add the .gz file as well in the backup.

Comment: You can save your tar.gz file somewhere else than current directory: cd /www; tar -czf /backups/backup.tar.gz .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is:

```
tar --strip-components 1 -xvf backup.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--transform` option to change the beginning of the archived file names to something else. As an example, in my case I had installed owncloud in directory named `sscloud` instead of `owncloud`. This caused problems when upgrading from the `*.tar` file. So I used the transform option like so:

```
tar xvf owncloud-10.3.2.tar.bz2 --transform='s/owncloud/sscloud/' --overwrite
```

The transform option takes `sed`-like commands. The above will replace the first occurrence of `owncloud` with `sscloud`.